# PHP & MYSQL: Echo not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I used to store all my data in 000webhost, today I decided to move to hostinger. So.. after moving it I replaced the old mysql_connect info by the new one. Alright, after doing that I tested it, everything has ran fine, except some echo functions.

check file (connects to the server and do the login):

```
    <?php

    $servidorr = "mysql.XXXX.co.uk";
    $bdd = "XXXXXXXX";
    $usuarioo = "XXXXX";
    $senhaa = "XXXXXXX";


    if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['usuario']) OR empty($_POST['senha']))) {
        header("Location: geton"); exit;
    }


    mysql_connect($servidorr, $usuarioo, $senhaa) or trigger_error(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($bdd) or trigger_error(mysql_error());

    $usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
    $senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);
    $lang = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lang']);


    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome`, `nivel` FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`usuario` = '". $usuario ."') AND (`senha` = '". sha1($senha) ."') AND (`ativo` = 1) LIMIT 1";
    $updatelang = "UPDATE usuarios SET lang='$lang' WHERE usuario='$usuario'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {

        echo "<script>alert('Oops! Looks like there is something wrong with your login! *perhaps a typo or you did not fill out the fields*'); location.href='geton'</script>"; exit;
    } else {

        $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
      mysql_query($updatelang);


        if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

        $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id'];
        $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
      $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado['usuario'];
        $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = $resultado['nivel'];
      $_SESSION['lang'] = $resultado['lang'];

        header("Location: http://mapmaking.zz.mu/pages/home"); exit;
    }

    ?>


Home file (these echos are just for testing and this is not the original file, the original one has the same php stuff, except the echo functions, those are in random lines):

<?php


if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

  $tlang = $_SESSION['UsuarioLang'];
  $aclevel = $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'];
  $nick = $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'];

$neededal = 1;
if (!isset($_SESSION['UsuarioID']) OR ($_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] < $neededal)) {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: http://inside.mapmaking.uk.to/geton"); exit;


}

session_start();

echo $tlang;
echo $aclevel;
echo $nick;
echo "$level$tlang$tlang";


?>
```

[this one basically start the session and check if the connected user acess level is 1]

Echo **$tlang** does not work! :( somehow it doesn’t, I have no idea why ;_;

Hope you guys help me, thank you!!

Comment: What does `print_r( $_SESSION );` output?

Comment: Edited this comment, I don't want to post your data. Still, people can check the historial... So, I recommend you to change it.

Comment: I have updated your question. YOu have to be careful posting your database's information (username, password) in public forums like this one.

Comment: It would probably be better to delete this question and re-post it since it stays in the edit history.

Comment: If I was you I'd change your password as you can still view the history on this

Comment: $_SESSION['lang'] != $_SESSION['UsuarioLang']

Comment: Thanks, Hanlet. I forgot to hide it! No problem anyway, this is just the "test" database I’m using. @Shomz let me try it

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION['lang'] != $_SESSION['UsuarioLang']

You assign a value to the first one, yet expect value from the second one.

`$_SESSION['lang'] = $resultado['lang'];`

`$tlang = $_SESSION['UsuarioLang'];`

Answer (score -1):

Change this line:

```
$_SESSION['lang'] = $resultado['lang'];
```

to the following:

```
$_SESSION['UsuarioLang'] = $resultado['lang'];
```

You should also call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) without the `isset` check. Also, you should consider using `&&` instead of `AND` and `||` instead of `OR`, as PHP has weird [operator precedence rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) (the assignment `=` has a higher precendence than either `AND` or `OR`).

Comment: @Shomz What do you mean by "stealing" answers? I posted this when I saw no other answers.